# One Sitemap image per language, possible?

Tags: seo, sitemap, multilingual

I generate a [sitemap image](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/178636?vid=1-635753330792570943-3498756790084937771&hl=en) file which looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
        xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
  <url>
    <loc>https://mywebsite.com/en/VISION-ART/image/boy-with-pipe-pablo-picasso</loc>
    <image:image>
      <image:loc>https://mywebsite.com/include/php/render/framed/VR/1/image/VndpwKicqcA%3D/ver//frame/gold-bronze-b88-1/borderSize/0.90/mat/fa3caad76c/matSize/6/matSizePercent/12/maxSize/500/minSize/400/le-garcon-a-la-pipe-pablo-picasso.jpg</image:loc>
      <image:title>Boy with pipe - PABLO PICASSO</image:title>
      <image:caption>Boy with pipe - PABLO PICASSO, art photography of VISION D&apos;ART. , smokehouse, pipe, boy, worker, blue work, painting, smoke, PABLO PICASSO</image:caption>
    </image:image>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>https://mywebsite.com/en/VISION-ART/image/the-dream-pablo-picasso</loc>
    <image:image>
      <image:loc>https://mywebsite.com/include/php/render/framed/VR/1/image/VndowKicqcA%3D/ver//frame/gold-bronze-b88-1/borderSize/0.90/mat/26ecae929f/matSize/6/matSizePercent/12/maxSize/500/minSize/400/le-reve-pablo-picasso.jpg</image:loc>
      <image:title>The dream - PABLO PICASSO</image:title>
      <image:caption>The dream - PABLO PICASSO, art photography of VISION D&apos;ART. , sleep, dream, PABLO PICASSO, oil painting, painting, drawing, abstract, woman</image:caption>
    </image:image>
  </url>
...
</urlset>
```

Can I generate others sitemap image for others language.
For, the same image page, `<loc></loc>` will be different, for example, for french version :

```
    https://mywebsite.com/en/VISION-ART/image/the-dream-pablo-picasso 
>>> 
    https://mywebsite.com/fr/VISION-ART/image/le-reve-pablo-picasso
```

And of course, title and caption will be different as well.

But `<image:loc></image:loc>` will remain the same.

So, can I generate one sitemap image per language ? And how to tell google for which language the sitemap image is for?